# IF SET Help Oracle to DB2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, sql-pl

I have to migrate all procedures from Oracle to DB2 database.  I'd like to know, how do I do **SET** syntax inside of **IF** as Oracle works.

Variable has been using in Oracle is `ps_iPkCooperativa` and are receiving 0.

**Oracle Code :**

```
BEGIN
    SELECT CCOOP
      INTO ps_iPkCooperativa
      FROM COOP
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
        THEN  ps_iPkCooperativa := 0;
END;
```

How do I do this in DB2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make such a conversion to db2 :

```
    BEGIN ATOMIC
     DECLARE ps_iPkCooperativa INT;

        SELECT CCOOP
          INTO ps_iPkCooperativa
          FROM COOP;         
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' -- means no_data_found
          SET MESSAGE_TEXT='No Data Found ';
          SET ps_iPkCooperativa = 0;
    END@
```

where

> The *ATOMIC* compound statement, as the name suggests, can be thought of
>   as a singular whole—if any unhandled error conditions arise within it,
>   all statements which have been executed up to that point are
>   considered to have failed as well and are therefore rolled back.
>   *ATOMIC* compound statements cannot be nested inside other *ATOMIC*
>   compound statements.
>
> In addition, you cannot use *SAVEPOINT*s or issue explicit *COMMIT*s or
>   ROLLBACKs from within an ATOMIC compound statement.
>
> **NOTE**
>
> *COMMIT*, *ROLLBACK*, *SAVEPOINTS* and nested *ATOMIC* compound statements are
>   not allowed within an ATOMIC compound statement.

Comment: Barbaros Ozhan , i did query above , but when i try to execute on db2 , show me thats not able to do it .


   `SELECT 
      CCOOP
    INTO ps_iPkCooperativa
    FROM GPRSD001.COOP;
    SIGNAL  SQLSTATE '02000' 
 SET ps_iPkCooperativa = 0;`

Comment: Tells me that i have to put semicolon end of '0200'

Comment: @Luiz yes, you're right, sorry. I've added `SET MESSAGE_TEXT='No Data Found ';` part.